# Django auth.authenticate keeps returning None

Tags: python, django, authentication

When I try to authenticate a user so they can login, auth.authenticate keeps returning none

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique = True, db_index = True, blank = False)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    role = {}
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()
```

views.py:

```
def user_signup_save(request):
    fname = request.POST.get('fname')
    lname = request.POST.get('lname')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = User(fname = fname, lname = lname, email = email)
    user.set_password('password')

    user.save()
    return HttpResponse(user.password)


def login(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = auth.authenticate(email = email , password = password)
    print user
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse("valid, logged in")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("invalid, not logged in")
    pass
```

Also, after a user signs up and they are stored in the db, when I try to compare their password using `check_password(string)`, it always returns false when when I use the raw and hashed passwords. The backend I'm am using is `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
user.set_password('password')
```

You are setting the password as the string `password` instead of the user typed password. Hence the issue

Change that to

```
user.set_password(password) #Note the quotes around the variable password
```

Use `password` as the password for the existing users, and you would be amazed to see that that `authenticate` responds the way intended ;)